# Dar unset numa variável após clicar num link

Tags: php, html

Ajudem me pessoal queria saber se é possivel dar unset numa variável através de um click num link através do action ou outra solução?

```
  <a href="login.php" class="login" action=""><span class="navbarcolors"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   echo 'logout'; 
}
else
{

   echo 'login';

}?>
```

Comment: Sim. Verifica se existe a session. Se tiver. Faz unset.

Comment: Mais se quer fazer em uma variável ou session?

Comment: Verificar já está a verificar! Agora preciso que ao clicar no link que faça unset a variável username porque assim quando a variável existir faz echo logout e se clicar para dar logout faça unset para echo login entende o que quero fazer?

Comment: quero dar unset $_SESSION[´username´] quando o link é pressionado!

Comment: Unset($_SESSION[“username”]; simples. Dentro da condição que verifica se tá logado.

Comment: Mas eu quero que deia unset quando o link for clicado há alguma possibilidade de fazer isso?

Comment: Sim. No caso. Qual é o script login? Vai na página de login né? Chegar lá você pode verificar se está logado. Se tiver. Você quebra a sessão. O correto era você ter um link pra um script somente para fazer logout.

Comment: Crie um script logout.php. Quebre ele lá quando for acionado. Aí na tua página faça uma condição para exibir o link. Se tem sessão username mostre o link de logout. Se não tem mostre o de login.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível alterar uma variável/sessão do PHP através do *JavaScript* (sem *AJAX*). O que você pode fazer é adicionar um parâmetro na *URL* e verificar no arquivo a ação do usuário, por exemplo.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    /**
     * Verifica se o parâmetro `action` existe na URL
     * Verifica se o valor do parâmetro `action` é "logout"
     * Verifica se a sessão existe
     *
     * Caso todas as condições acima sejam verdadeira, remove a sessão.
     */
    if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "logout" && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
    }

    /* Captura a ação */
    $action = !isset($_SESSION['username']) ? "login" : "logout";
?>

<a href="index.php?action=<?php echo $action ?>" class="login" action=""><span class="navbarcolors"><?php echo $action ?></span></a>

<?php
    /* ATENÇÃO! Adicionei a linha abaixo, SOMENTE por não saber como você está trabalhando com o formulário de login, ela é apenas para um teste. */
    $_SESSION['username'] = "ok";
?>
```

**Demonstração:**

[image: Demonstração do código]

Comment: Não funcionou!!

Comment: Quando faço login com as informações corretas o botão mostra login na mesma!

Comment: Se possível testa com essa nova modificação

Comment: Ele tá mudando o botão de login para logout quando o login é correto! Mas depois clico em logout e o botão se mantém igual!

Comment: Não se canse mais tou notando agora um problema é que minha href vai para a página login.php mas quando o utilizador faz login com sucesso manda para index.php e quando ele faz logout queria que fosse para index.php mas mostra-se o botão a dizer login!

Comment: Vamos um problema de cada vez. Adicionei uma demonstração na resposta. Como eu não sei como você está utilizando o formulário de login, não consigo elaborar um código mais preciso para seu problema, mas como você pode ver, o código está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: têm teamviewer ou algo que me possa ajudar diretamente?